# Sending mail from unix shell script

Tags: email, shell, attachment

I need to send my report.txt file to given mail address from my shell script.I tried this one:

```
  mailx -s "report" target@mail.com < report.txt
```

it didn't send and it didn't give any error messages or something.
Why it didn't work , i think it should be work ,there is no mistake in form.
I use cent-os 5.7. I tried reinstall heirloom-mailx and it didnt fix.
Beside, if you know any alternative way to send it, it will be help me too.

Comment: What do your logs say? Check /var/log/messages and your mail log.

Comment: Anything in the logs? Does it work at the console?

Comment: how can i do that? i wrote that in terminal and i get "bash: /var/log/messages: Permission denied"

Comment: no it doensn't work in console too

Comment: Use a pager -- `less /var/log/messages` -- and learn a little more Unix stuff ;)

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you did not set up your `smtp` (outgoing mail) server correctly. There are several options, and you can even use your gmail account with e.g. `ssmtp`. Or Postfix. Or sendmail.

If it's set up, maybe the service is not running.

For the problem, I'd first check what your logs says (e.g. `/var/log/messages*`.

HTH